# Sign XML with ECDsa and SHA256 in .Net

Tags: c#, cryptography, ecdsa, cng, signedxml

I'm trying to use SignedXml in .Net with ECDsa (ECDsaCng) and SHA256 and I'm getting an "CryptographicException" with message "Failed to create signing key.". Does someone knows how to achieve that goal or if I should know relevant information about .net support for ecdsa? thank you in advance.

```
public XmlDocument SignXml(XmlDocument xmlDoc)
    {
        CngKey cngKey = CngKey.Create(CngAlgorithm.ECDsaP256);
        ecDsaCng = new ECDsaCng(cngKey);
        ecDsaCng.HashAlgorithm = CngAlgorithm.ECDsaP256;
        ecDsaCng.KeySize = 256;

        xmlDoc.PreserveWhitespace = true;

        SignedXml signedXml = new SignedXml(xmlDoc);
        signedXml.SigningKey = ecDsaCng;

        Reference reference = new Reference();
        reference.Uri = "";
        XmlDsigEnvelopedSignatureTransform env = new XmlDsigEnvelopedSignatureTransform();
        reference.AddTransform(env);
        signedXml.AddReference(reference);

        signedXml.ComputeSignature();

        XmlElement xmlDigitalSignature = signedXml.GetXml();
        xmlDoc.DocumentElement.AppendChild(xmlDoc.ImportNode(xmlDigitalSignature, true));
        return xmlDoc;
    }
```

Error appears in "signedXml.ComputeSignature();" method call.

Comment: Removed my answer as it didn't fix the issue. I think the error for that one is more clear: not supported is better than a failure to create the signing key (especially since Microsoft has the tendency to not distinguish between algorithm and key). EC support is very restricted on Microsoft platforms.

Comment: What do you exactly mean with "EC support is very restricted on Microsoft platforms." ?

Comment: There is little support for domain parameters, algorithms and within protocols. ECDSA is supported for NIST curves in certificates but I'm not so sure about dig-sig.

Comment: And, just for information, where can I find further information? It's not enough clear for me. Otherwise, thank you very much for your help.

Comment: I really wish I knew. I've spend ages browsing MS documentation. It's usually correct but not always complete.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have a look in the assembly

> [System.Security, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral,
>   PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a]

in the method

> public void ComputeSignature()

Only **RSA** and **DSA** keys are accepted. It is a shame that it isn't specified somewhere on the [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/System.Security.Cryptography.Xml.SignedXml(v=vs.110).aspx). You will have to pass on the SignedXml class.

Comment: Thank you very much, I finally managed to use BouncyCastle, keep waiting for ECDSA implementation in .NET Framework platform.

Comment: can you please share the implementation @Alejandro Morán

Comment: @AlejandroMorán How did you manage it ? Can you share it with us  ?

Comment: @Freeedy Sorry I don't have that code anymore but I finally managed to solve this by using BouncyCastle library.

Comment: @AlejandroMorán  I have the same problem  ((